# Jekyll site missing posts when hosted locally; works fine on Github

Tags: jekyll

I'm using [this](https://github.com/ssokurenko/jekyll-smart-material) template with my [site](https://github.com/buschnyj/buschnyj.github.io), and github pages hosts it fine. However, when I host it locally, all but one of my posts goes missing.

Inspect Element doesn't give me errors.
rebuilding _site folder causes the same problems.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

bundler 1.14.3
jekyll 3.4.0
rvm 1.28
ruby 2.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post filenames should have the date in the format: `YYYY-MM-DD` and then the rest of the name, actually you have posts like:

```
_posts/
├── 2015-1-20-carbon-fiber-forklift-arms.markdown
├── 2015-10-23-smart-seatbelt.markdown
├── 2015-3-12-cooling-fan.markdown
├── 2016-3-12-photogammetry.markdown
└── 2016-5-23-Newton's-Apple.markdown
```

The only post you can see now is `2015-10-23-smart-seatbelt.markdown` because of the month format, their months should be with two digits, just preppend a 0 and they will get published

```
_posts/
├── 2015-01-20-carbon-fiber-forklift-arms.markdown
├── 2015-10-23-smart-seatbelt.markdown
├── 2015-03-12-cooling-fan.markdown
├── 2016-03-12-photogammetry.markdown
└── 2016-05-23-Newton's-Apple.markdown
```

Comment: Good catch. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Posts with valid date format should work. It should be YYYY-MM-DD-

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you should make sure, that the date is not in the future, so the posts date field should have a date in the past. Also the *time must be valid*!

So creating a post with the time of 12 o'clock for today and testing it at 10 o'clock the same day won't show up!